# Book/course recommendation on game theory application to multi-agent system (reinforcement learning)

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, game-theory, multi-agent-systems, books

Is there any great game theory book or course that discusses the application of game theory to **modern** reinforcement learning or multi-agent systems? Or a classic reference book that can help me get a full understanding of papers like [$\alpha$-rank](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-45619-9).

Comment: "game theory to modern reinforcement learning or multi-agent systems" Why "to"? Do you mean any book, which narrated how the Game Theory evolved to Reinforce Learning?